# How to get docker apero/cas server working on localhost?

Tags: docker, cas

I tried the following:

docker pull apereo/cas
docker run -p 80:8080 -p 443:8443 -d --name="cas" apereo/cas:v5.2.2

I then do:

```
docker exec -it /bin/bash
```

I set the etc/cas/cas.properties file with:

```
cas.tgc.crypto.encryption.key=
cas.tgc.crypto.signing.key=
cas.webflow.crypto.signing.key=
cas.webflow.crypto.encryption.key=
```

(and fill in the autogenerated keys populated after running ./bin/run-cas.sh)

I then run:

> keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias cas -keystore thekeystore
>   -storepass changeit -validity 9999 -keysize 2048

Problem is, when I try rerunning ./bin/run-cas.sh, I am getting error:

> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to
>   start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be
>   misconfigured.

Is there something else I need to do to get started by getting CAS running on my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the container, it executes whatever ENTRYPOINT or CMD is in the Dockerfile. [In the case of apero/cas](https://github.com/apereo/cas-webapp-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) that would be `CMD ["/cas-overlay/bin/run-cas.sh"]`. What's likely happening is this script runs cas in some capacity and utilizes port 8443.

Now when you `docker exec` into the container, you're running an *additional* process in the container. You are a different process. You can see what I'm talking about if you `ps aux` inside the container, you will see the CMD running via bash. Now when you run `run-cas.sh`, it attempts to run something (again) using port 8443, but that port it already allocated in the container, and so you get the error.

Try this. `docker run -p 80:8080 -p 443:8443 -d --name="cas" apereo/cas:v5.2.2 /bin/bash`. When you add `/bin/bash` to the end, you're overriding the CMD in the Dockerfile, so the first `run-cas.sh` doesn't run, and 8443 isn't allocated to a process. This is similar in function to using `docker exec`, except you're running bash *before* the initial command executes. Then you should be able to do all the things you're trying to do (I know nothing about cas) without this port 8443 error.